# drupal_static() uses a FUNCTION variable,what does it mean?

Tags: caching

```
function drupal_set_page_content($content = NULL) {
  $content_block = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__, NULL);
  $main_content_display = &drupal_static('system_main_content_added', FALSE);

  if (!empty($content)) {
    $content_block = (is_array($content) ? $content : array('main' => array('#markup' => $content)));
  }
  else {
    $main_content_display = TRUE;
    return $content_block;
  }
}
```

This snippet is pasted from common.inc. We pass in a `__FUNCTION__` to  [`drupal_static()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_static/7) but I do not know what this variable means. Does it mean a cache for the outer function itself? How does it work? I do not see any data handled inside the function before it returns `$content_block`.

Answer (score 35):

`__FUNCTION__` is one of the so-called [Magic Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) of PHP.

All it does is return a string with the name of the function that the constant is contained in.

For example:

```
function my_strangely_named_function() {
  print __FUNCTION__;
}
```

The above will print 'my_strangely_named_function'.

Drupal uses this constant with its static cache so that each cache is identifiable from any other function, and as such can be identifiably cleared.

To use an abridged version of your code:

```
function drupal_set_page_content($content = NULL) {
  $content_block = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__, NULL);
}
```

Any other function in the Drupal lifecycle can call:

```
drupal_static_reset('drupal_set_page_content');
```

And that will clear the cache for that specific function, so that next time it's called the data is built up as if from new.

That's just the basic use of the static cache pattern, you can find more information and examples on the [documentation page for `drupal_static()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_static/7) itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,I now understand what does this FUNCTION mean,but further more,where is this $content_block variable first created,as all I can find in this code is it retrieves data from cache,but where is the cache created in the first place,thank you !

Comment: Are you familiar with static variables in PHP in general?

Comment: to the first comment, and augmenting the second, the 'cache' is created in the TRUE branch of the `if` statement

Comment: What @Jimajamma said, plus the fact that `drupal_static` keeps hold of a registry of caches for all functions in the system that use it.

Comment: This might be a showcase of my PHP ignorance, but - anyway: why do they say in entityreference: `drupal_static`, rather than `&drupal_static`?

Comment: @Artur It's probably a bug in the code to be honest, the correct use of the static cache pattern is [pretty well documented](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_static/7). Either it works because the function itself is declared by reference (`function &drupal_static(...`), or it actually doesn't work at all and there's no static caching in the entityreference module

Comment: Yes, that's why I asked, having looked at the docs page that you mention. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 3):

In depth information you will get at http://blogs.sourceallies.com/2012/02/static-caching-in-drupal/. Here is a quote from it:

> ... caching (of any kind, not just static caching) is to be done in a responsible manner. Overzealous usage of caching floods memory which can crash high traffic websites. Remember also that caching should be used for large data structures that are expensive to generate. Lastly, use caching only if you know for sure that what you cache will be needed again (e.g., menu data in Drupal). There’s no point caching a list of names or addresses or colors if that list will never be used again. That would be like saving your old car tires after you put new ones on.